# Why does DOMPurify with SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES removes data attributes?

Tags: javascript, security, vue.js, xss, dompurify

I stumbled across a weird behavior of [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) where `data-*` attributes get left when sanitizing with the default options, but get stripped out when using the `SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES` option. Also, the *whole* text that contains a template gets stripped out instead of just the template part.

Are these bugs or features? What is the rationale for these?

```js
const dirty = '<span data-foo="bar"> Hello {{ World }} </span>';

console.log(
  DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty)
  // expected <span data-foo="bar"> Hello {{ World }} </span>
  // actual   <span data-foo="bar"> Hello {{ World }} </span>
);

console.log(
  DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, { SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES: true })
  // expected <span data-foo="bar"> Hello </span>
  // actual   <span>  </span>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dompurify@2.0.0/dist/purify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that in [the docs](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#can-i-configure-dompurify) they say
> this mode is not recommended for production usage.
// allowing template parsing in user-controlled HTML is not advised at all.

Comment: @RoyJ yup I read that ;) But thanks! Did you stumble across some docs that explains in details what is the expected behavior and/or rationale behind the `SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES` options?

Comment: I don't have a definite answer for you, but I note that Knockout uses `data-` attributes for its bindings, so maybe that's the rationale.